# Dataset with low and non-linearly correlated variables: suggestions on modelling strategies

Tags: modeling, negative-binomial-distribution, generalized-additive-model, lm, nonlinearity

I have a dataset with low and non-linearly correlated variables and I am interested in assessing the relations between the Independent Variable (IV) and Dependent Variable (DV), however I am not able to find a very good model. I ask for advice from more expert researchers on the results of the analysis conducted so far, and on how to proceed to find a better model.

Below I describe the dataset and what I tried.

**Data**
DV is highly skewed count data (here non transformed and log-transformed histogram)

[image]

These are the Pearson correlation (but with useful bivariate plot) of the variables (non-transformed in the first plot, and log-transformed in the second plot)

[image]

[image]

**What I tried so far**

I tried to fit many different models, on both non-transformed and transformed data.
For instance I tried a linear model on log-transformed data but residuals suggest it doesn't work, mostly due to non-linearity of residuals and strong heteroskedasticity.

[image]

I also tried a negative binomial model, more adapt to count skewed data. The algorithm didn't converge and I had to set the maximum number of iteration to 600.  Below the residuals of the model using plot(model). I know residuals of this model are difficult to diagnostic with these plots and there is a dedicated package called DhARMA that helps in assessing the fit. However, this package finds some errors in the model so it doesn't work (the error says: "Context: Simulations from your fitted model produce NA values. DHARMa cannot calculated residuals for this. This is nearly certainly an error of the regression package you are using")

[image]

I also tried a GAM model. I tried both a GAM with negative binomial family and with a Gaussian family (in this case fitted on log-transformed data). In the first case (negative binomial GAM) the residuals seems "strange" as in the previous case, in the second case (Gaussian on log-transformed data) the fit seems better (despite some heteroskedasticity). Below the negative binomial and gaussian plot of residuals.

[image]

[image]

I think that the better – although not perfect – model among these is the GAM gaussian on log-transformed data.

However, I am not sure this is a suitable solution, if I can accept it because is the better among the others and with acceptable residuals, or what should I try to find some better model.

In the end I'd like to ask you: do you have any comments or suggestions on what I have done so far, on the models I tried, and on how to proceed with the analysis in order to find a good model for this dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts as you have requested.

First, you have already performed extensive data examination, which is appropriate to formulate a hypothetical relation for new (or, out-of-sample) data.

Next, if this is econometric-based data, for example, explore the underlying error generating process as suggested by those with a fundamental understanding of the field in question (aka, talk to an economist).

There is also the point of why a model with essentially a mean focus? For example, here is a source discussing various areas of applications of quantile regression: [Quantile Regression Models and Their Applications: A Review](https://www.hilarispublisher.com/open-access/quantile-regression-models-and-their-applications-a-review-2155-6180-1000354.pdf). To quote from the abstract:

> Quantile regression (QR) has received increasing attention in recent years and applied to wide areas such as investment, finance, economics, medicine and engineering. Compared with conventional mean regression, QR can characterize the entire conditional distribution of the outcome variable, may be more robust to outliers and misspecification of error distribution, and provides more comprehensive statistical modeling than traditional mean regression. QR models could not only be used to detect heterogeneous effects of covariates at different quantiles of the outcome, but also offer more robust and complete estimates compared to the mean regression, when the normality assumption violated or outliers and long tails exist. These advantages make QR attractive and are extended to apply for different types of data, including independent data, time-to-event data and longitudinal data.

So, perhaps a few different avenues of investigation to further explore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, these are good suggestions...

Comment: Since there are no other answers and that of @AJKOER contains useful suggestions, I am going to accept it